# Why does RNA synthesis in E.coli begin with a Purine?

Tags: molecular-biology, transcription

From Berg's Biochemistry:

> Most newly synthesized RNA chains carry a highly distinctive tag on the 5′ end: the first base at that end is either pppG or pppA.

Is there a reason why the synthesis initiates with a purine?

Comment: From [this](http://mcb.asm.org/content/16/10/5801.full.pdf) paper, which is the 2nd result of a Google search for `rna synthesis begin with purine`, the abstract ends with this sentence: *`"Our results suggest that the purine-rich sequences at the 5' ends of the nascent transcripts of many genes act to stabilize the early ternary complex."`* You can read the papers citing this one to learn more if you wish.

Comment: I didn't find any suitable result with the keywords I was using. Anyways thank you. @MattDMo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Purine-rich sequences at the 5' ends of the nascent transcripts of many genes act to stabilize the early ternary(elongation) complex.

P.S.Source: MattDMo's comment.